# Connection to Linux host machine's specific port inside a Dokcer container

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose, cloud

Im running a few `Docker` containers via `docker-compose` in Linux Ubuntu 20.04. My docker compose config is like this:
version: "3"

```
networks:
  app_net:
     external: true

services:
  client-service:
    image: client-image
    container_name: client-service-con
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ../clients/web/:/home/cl/clients/web
    working_dir: "/home/cl/clients/web"
    expose:
      - 80
    networks:
      - app_net
```

Right now I want to connect to an active socks5 proxy in linux host machine like this:

```
socks5://172.18.0.0:2080
```

But I get `"failed: Connection refused"` error. When my host machine is Mac OS, Im doing like this and it works:

```
socks5://host.docker.internal:2080
```

But when my host machine is Linux, there is no luck and I can connect. Im trying to ping host machine from container like this:

```
nc -vz 172.18.0.1 2080
```

But I get the same error.
When I do ping:

```
ping 172.18.0.1
```

I get this:

```
PING 172.18.0.1 (172.18.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.327 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.097 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.154 ms
```

What I have to do?
My Docker version is: 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
My Host Linux Machine is: ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

You should set network_mode to "host" in your docker-compose.yml as follows:

`network_mode: "host"`

Are you able to use Docker Swarm?  If so then maybe this would work:

```
networks:
  app_net:
     external: true
  host:
    external:
      name: host

services:
  client-service:
    image: client-image
    container_name: client-service-con
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ../clients/web/:/home/cl/clients/web
    working_dir: "/home/cl/clients/web"
    expose:
      - 80
    networks:
      - app_net
      - host
```

Comment: I have several containers that connect to each other via external "app_net" network. when I want to add network_mode, It says you can not have networks section in docker-compose file. What I have to do?

Comment: Also adding network_mode: "host" not solved my problem

Comment: No Im not familiar with Docker Swarm. This config is not for docker-compose?

Comment: Documentation for Docker Swarm mode is here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm You can enable swarm mode on a single host simply by running 'docker swarm init'.